# Gap between lines and axis with C3

Tags: c3

How can I delete the space between the axis and the lines with C3 library ?

[image]

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

Tnx

Answer (score 5):

Just set the axis padding

```
axis: {
    x: {
        padding: 0
    },
    y: {
        padding: {
            bottom: 0
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/50o0ve7k/